# Should I use "Spread Spectrum Clocking" on my new Western Digital disk?

Tags: hard-drive

I just received the Western Digital Caviar Green (WD5000AADS). I noticed it has a jumper setting "**Spread Spectrum Clocking**". I read somewhere this is a trade-off between speed and reduced electromagnetic noise.

1. Is that understanding accurate, or what is the setting for exactly?
2. Why should I consider enabling it? (I have two other hard disks that will be nearby, if this makes a difference.)

Comment: See this article......http://zone.ni.com/devzone/cda/tut/p/id/4154

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Many hardware devices that put out enough electromagnetic interference, or EMI, to interfere with the reception of TVs and radios have a feature known as spread spectrum clocking (SSC). However, SSC is not well understood by many people. It is usually disabled by default. You have the option of turning it on or off, but it's best to leave it disabled.
>   Digital systems such as computers synchronize the activity of multiple elements through the use of a clock signal or a pulse. This signal usually exists in a narrow band of frequencies. If it's intense enough at those frequencies, it can violate FCC rules about how much EMI a device rated for certain use can put out.
>
> SSC tries to get around this problem by shaping the emissions -- i.e., varying the frequencies used -- so that instead of the clock using one narrow frequency range, it's spread out over a number of different ones at a much lower

[Source Of information](http://searchwindowsserver.techtarget.com/tip/Leave-spread-spectrum-clocking-disabled)

Other resources

http://zone.ni.com/devzone/cda/tut/p/id/4154

http://wdc.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/3641/~/what-is-spread-spectrum-clocking-(ssc)-and-does-it-need-to-be-enabled

http://spuder.wordpress.com/2011/08/04/ssc-spread-spectrum-clocking-hard-drives/

Comment: The zone.ni.com and wdc.custhelp.com links are most relevant/trustworthy for me, I think. Plus this link (http://www.wdc.com/en/library/eide/2579-001037.pdf) from Psycogeek's answer. The best answer for me would cite just those three, but your answer comes the closest.

Answer (score 2):

It really depends if you need to use it or not. If you will be using sensitive equipment such as in a lab with the computer then you should use the SSC. Otherwise it will not really make a difference for you and you'll sacrifice a bit of speed.

Answer (score 2):

I would leave it as it came to me, unless I had special needs, then I would change it.

I do not believe that in this situation that any speed difference could ever be seen between the two different settings, even after advanced benchmarking repeatedly and averaging the results.

http://www.wdc.com/en/library/eide/2579-001037.pdf

### SATA Hard Drive Jumper Settings WD SATA

> WD SATA hard drives are factory set for workstation/desktop  use. For
>   enterprise storage requirements, the jumpers can be set to  enable
>   spread spectrum clocking or power-up in standby modes. WD SATA drives
>   are shipped from the factory **either** with or  without a jumper
>   shunt in the spread spectrum clocking (SSC)  enable/disable position
>   (on pins 1 and 2). It is not necessary  to add or remove the jumper
>   shunt on the drive for  workstation/desktop use. For enterprise
>   storage enviroments, use  the following advanced settings:
>
> SSC Mode (Default 1): spread spectrum clocking feature enabled  or
>   disabled. Default 1 setting is disabled or jumper shunt placed  on
>   pins 1–2. Removing the jumper enables the spread spectrum  clocking
>   feature.
>
> SSC Mode (Default 2): spread spectrum clocking feature enabled  or
>   disabled. Default 2 setting is disabled or no jumper shunt  placed on
>   pins 1–2. Adding the jumper to pins 1–2 enables the  spread spectrum
>   clocking feature.

Who writes this stuff! I still cannot read it the way it is in the original document (last sentence looks incorrect)... **Put the jumper on 1-2 to disable SSC** Would that be so hard to say?

In rare situtions where there might be a frequency issue based on country, with stuff similar to this (not nessiarily this) they will often ship to that country with it set to work in that country or location.

---

[G5 Mac Issue with SSC](http://www.xlr8yourmac.com/archives/nov05/111405.html#S20102)

> Last week there were several posts on problems with SerialATA hard
>   drives with SSC (Spread Spectrum Clocking) enabled when using the
>   onboard G5 SATA and with some (not all) Mac PCI SATA cards.
>   . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
>
> We and Firmtek have found problems with certain SATA drives which have
>   SSC turned on and therefore will NOT work

---

[Rectron-cpt](http://www.rectron-cpt.net/support_tech09apr06.htm)

Users thinking thier Seagate hard drive is Dead or DOA in situations, they used a Segate utility to disable SSC.

and the opposite apparently:

> Some users have been using other brands of HDD’s (in RAID
>   configurations) on the Intel Matrix Storage with the ICH7R on the 945
>   and 955 chipset and have reported that the system crashes during the
>   installation with a **BSOD**. They have blamed the motherboard and memory
>   but this is not the case. This is **because SSC is disabled** on the HDD.

and again:

[Seagate forum](http://forums.seagate.com/t5/Barracuda-XT-Barracuda-Barracuda/RAID-problems-with-7200-11-drives-unified-thread/td-p/26989/page/4)

> It seems as if all the controllers that have problems with SSC-enabled
>   drives are RAID controllers

Answer (score 1):

"Spread spectrum clocking" (SSC) lets a SATA-III (default 6 Gb/s) HDD be
recognized by a SATA-I (1.5 Gb/s-only) computer. The drive manufacturer
has to provide this capability to claim SATA compliance, but computer and
OS vendors don't want people to know it's there, so the manufacturer uses
obfuscating terminology and doesn't document SSC's real purpose anywhere.