# Does primary drive need to be plugged in to particular power port on cable?

Tags: ssd, power-supply, sata

I had temporarily taken out the SSD which is the primary drive to a PC. When I put it back in the computer wouldn't start and gave errors like "disk read error" or "no bootable media found". After trying various things, I found the problem was that a different port on the jumper cable connecting it to the power supply needed to be used? Is there something special about the particular port on the jumper cable? Out of curiousity I changed the port on the jumper cable that the secondary hard drive used and it didn't make a difference and it still was detected.

This was like [the problem where it said the CPU was over heating](https://superuser.com/questions/1072767/how-to-tell-if-cpu-is-actually-overheating-or-is-a-false-positive) because one outlet was specially designed for CPU fan.

If relevant the power cable was SATA and the SSD was connected by SATA-3.

Answer (score 3):

Reading your question I was confused here to start with but I think I understand now.

For those unfamiliar with the inside of the computer, for SATA drives you have a [SATA power cable](https://goo.gl/images/3HVSL7) and a [SATA data cable](https://goo.gl/images/w1yIAH).  The SATA power cables will be provided by the power supply unit and plug into the power port on the hard drive, and the SATA data cables plug into the data port on the hard drives and the required data [ports on the motherboard](https://goo.gl/images/h2oqrx).  IDE and some SATA drives have [jumpers](https://goo.gl/images/647nqU) for setting how you want them to run but SSD SATA drives generally don't have them.  Those that do have jumpers are for setting things like [spread spectrum clocking](https://superuser.com/questions/343069/should-i-use-spread-spectrum-clocking-on-my-new-western-digital-disk) and [reduced power spin-up](http://www.wdc.com/wdproducts/library/other/2579-001116.pdf)

That aside, each SATA port on the motherboard is numbered.  You need to plug the drive you want to boot into the [lowest numbered SATA port](http://www.alphr.com/features/378925/how-to-install-an-ssd) on the motherboard.

Comment: It seemed to me it made a different which SATA power cable was plugged into the primary drive.